# Plotting a function together with a range of different constant value parameters

Tags: matlab, function, plot

Mathematica easily plots a function with constant value parameters over a range of different values for the constant(s).

With MATLAB, is this possible?

For instance: would MATLAB allow me to plot `f(x)=x*e^a` of different constant values of `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how you define easily:

```
>> alpha = [0.1 0.2 0.5 1];
>> x = 0:0.01:2;
>> plot(x,exp(x(:)*alpha))
>> grid on
>> legend(arrayfun(@(a)sprintf('alpha = %.2f',a),alpha,'uni',false))
```

[image]

Comment: What does    x(:) denotes?

Comment: It converts the `x`, irrespective of how many elements or dimensions that it has, into a column vector.

Answer (score 3):

`fplot()` can also be used to plot functions.

```
alpha = [0.1 0.5 1];
f = (@(x) exp(alpha.*x));
fplot(f, [0,2]); grid on;    % Axis range = [0, 2]
legend('alpha=0.1', 'alpha=0.5', 'alpha=1.0');
```

And the output is:
[image: Output]