# Plotting a function together with a range of different constant value parameters in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot f(x) = a*(x**b) of different constant values of a and b? I want the plot to have a legend so one can easily distinguish different functions from each other.

Assume that a is a continuous variable in range (0,10] and b is a discrete variable in range [0,3].

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or a tutorial.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#

Comment: Thanks @wwii for the reply. I went through almost all the examples provided on the matplotlib.org to see if I can find my answer there. However, I was not able to find the correct answer and I do really appreciate if you can let me know if you are aware of any resources that can help me to solve this question

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html#d-surface-color-map is an example of a 3-d plot that uses a function and two independent variables (`X` and `Y`) to *create* the values for  the dependent variable (`Z`).

Comment: Actually I do not want the plot to be a 3D plot. I just need a plot like the one discussed here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383218/plotting-a-function-together-with-a-range-of-different-constant-value-parameters

Comment: There are examples showing plots with multiple lines from separate data.

Comment: In that discussion there was only one constant variable and the whole topic is to write the code in Matlab. However, I was wondering if the same thing can be done with Matplolib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

f = lambda x, a, b: a*np.power(x,b)
x = np.linspace(0, 0.6, 200)
alist = [0.1,3, 6,9]
blist = list(range(0,4))

for i in range(4): 
    y = [f(j, alist[i], blist[i]) for j in x] 
    plt.plot(x, y, label=(r'a='+ str(alist[i]))+ r', b='+str(blist[i]))
    plt.ylim(0, 0.5) 
plt.legend() 
plt.grid() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just one question, what if the range of a and b was different? For example, what if a belongs to range (1,5) and b to range (2,9)?

Comment: @shirinelahi Then you can calculate `y` under nested `for` loop. `for i in range(len(a)): for j in range(len(b)): y = [f(k, a[i], b[i]) for k in x] `